# Vindictive vs. Vindicative

Tags: meaning, etymology, word-usage

I recently came across a very informative answer here within the Stack Exchange network where the author uses the word **vindicative**. I assumed the author had meant **vindictive** (I didn't know vindicative was a word). Google also thought I meant to search for vindictive when I looked up vindicative but to my surprise there are plenty of online dictionaries that list it as a word.

Initially my thought was it was just a matter of a variation in spelling similar to the differences we see between American and British English (the author is British), but then I came across this explanation on [WikiDiff](http://wikidiff.com/vindicative/vindictive) which states the following:

> "As adjectives the difference between **vindictive** and **vindicative** is that vindictive is having a tendency to seek revenge when vengeful, while vindicative is having a tendency to vindicate."

What is the history/origin behind **vindictive** and **vindicative** and their respective meanings?

Comment: No spell-checker is comprehensive, and *vindicative* is a rare word. Never rely on automated spell-checkers, much less so-called grammar-checkers, to judge the acceptability of a word or phrase.

Comment: @choster Of course, I'm aware that software and tools like these are far from all-encompassing I was just curious as to why it appears to have been 'left behind'.

Comment: StackExchange does not have a spell check, it's your browser's. (Otherwise it wouldn't mark StackExchange as erroneous ;)) If it's Chrome, it's from the same company as Google Search. For performance reasons live services tend to skip rare words.

Comment: If you're asking why something is included in a spellcheck or not, it's really a question for the software publishers, and not about English per se. No possible spellchecker dictionary, with current technology, could encompass every possible variation of every possible word of any living language, especially since they also bundle many proper nouns that a print dictionary would omit— MS Word 2013 understands *Tatung* and *Coldplay* and *Atorvastatin*. *Vindicative* is relatively rare, and you need to set a cut off somewhere.

Comment: Also because *vindicative* is so rare, odds are that when people type it, they actually meant *vindictive* so the spell checker statistically helps more people by suggesting the “correction”

Comment: @Jim Good point.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the foibles of  spell-checkers are a matter for the programmers to deal with rather than a matter of English usage..

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Clearly the example of a spell checker wasn't the best because it definitely is not meant to be the focus of the question. Not sure why it's become the sole focus. The question is meant to address the differences between the two words and further history behind vindicative. I'll make an edit to clarify this when I get a chance.

Comment: Possibly because the only (two-part) question one can find in your post is '... why do Google and StackExchange's spell-check dictionary not recognize _vindicative_ as a word? Is it simply because of its lack of usage in our day and age?'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Except the part where I asked "Is it simply because of its lack of usage in our day and age?"

Comment: I said 'two-part question'. You essentially ask one off-topic question (about how programmers come to their decisions) and then suggest a possible answer to it. Try asking 'Have _vindictive_ and _vindicative_ a common origin? Is _vindicative_ commonly used nowadays?'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth And I thought the guys over at StackOverflow were bad! Little did I know they only scratch the surface, you guys really know how to critique the crap out of people :)

Comment: @bwegs - Yep, we're good at that here. Meta is filled with discussions on whether we're too harsh, or too soft...

Comment: @AndyT Or better yet, just right... My question seems to have been adequately re-shaped by the comments and edits after all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The two terms appears to  have a common origin, but "vindictive" has retained its original negative meaning while "vindicative" has also developed a more positive connotation:

From [Grammarphobia](http://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2009/11/the-light-side-and-the-dark.html):.

> - ***The verb vindicate comes from the Latin vindicare,*** meaning to claim, set free, punish, or avenge. In the 16th and 17th centuries, the English word reflected both the negative and positive sides of its Latin heritage.
> - ***First, it meant to avenge*** or exercise vengeance. ***Later it came to mean punish; rescue or set free;  justify or clear (as from suspicion or dishonor); establish possession of something; and make good or defend against encroachment.***

Origin of vindictive:

> - ***The adjective “vindictive”*** (from the Latin *vindicta*, meaning revenge), ***was preceded by an earlier form, “vindicative,” in the 1500s, and has had a generally grim history since entering English.***
> - When “vindictive” first showed up in the early 1600s, it described someone “given to revenge; having a revengeful disposition,” according to the Oxford English Dictionary.
>     In other words, someone who liked punishing people or holding a grudge.
> - In former days, “vindictive” was also used to describe anything punitive, retributive, or avenging. Today we use the legal phrase “punitive damages,” but the OED cites a quotation from 1813 about “vindictive damages.”

Both terms appear to derive from "vindication",

> - *The Chambers Dictionary of Etymology* suggests that **“vindicate” could be a back-formation from an earlier word, “vindication,” which first appeared in English in the late 1400s and originally meant the act of avenging.** (A back formation is a word formed by dropping a real or imagined part from another word.)
> - The OED says that “vindication” made its first published appearance in William Caxton’s printing of Aesop’s Fables **(1484)**: “An asse … smote hym [the lion] in the forhede with his feete by maner of vyndycacion.”

but through the centuries developed different nuances:

> - ***So both “vindicate” and “vindictive” come from notions of vengeance and punishment. Although “vindictive” has continued to embrace the dark side, “vindicate” has lightened up.***

Comment: A good answer to the question OP actually says they meant to ask.